# Clone chrome CTRL + F implementation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anybody give me a way to clone Chrome's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> functionality?
I tried in JavaScript with Regex.

```
let sourceHTML = ele.innerHTML;

if (sourceHTML.match(regExFinder)) {
  sourceHTML = sourceHTML.replace(regExFinder, `<span class='highlight'>$&</span>`);
  ele.innerHTML = sourceHTML;
}
```

The problem is when I try to search "an" and my sourceHTML is `<span>is an</span>` it replaces "an" inside `<span></span>` tag too.
Can anybody give me a proper way to do this?

Comment: Try iterating through the elements' text contents (`.textContent` and `.value`) instead of HTMLs.

Comment: @junvar can you give me a demo for that?